# How do you qualify for Overwatch?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

As of 2019, how does one become eligible to do Overwatch cases in CSGO? I am currently at 142 wins & MG2.

What do you need to unlock this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements to participate in Overwatch are left unclear, but the general consensus is at minimum you will need:

• 150 competitive wins minimum

• Rank greater than Silver in Competitive Ranks

These requirements seem to be left vague purposefully to prevent bots and abuse. You can read more at [this CS:GO website](https://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/overwatch/)

Their FAQ page regarding qualifying for Overwatch states

> "Investigators are selected based on their CS:GO activity (competitive wins, account age, hours played, Skill Group, low report count, etc.) and, if applicable, prior Overwatch participation level and score (a function of their accuracy as an investigator). Community members who maintain both a high level of activity and high Overwatch scores will receive more cases to elect to participate in."

Comment: It also helps when you've been good and not have may or any reports against you AND also it helps when you have accurate reports against other players.